# React expand animation read more/ less dynamic height

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have Expand component and I'm trying to create expand animation on toggle with no success **I don't want to explicit the height of the element (I want it to be generic):

```
export const Expand = ({ startOpen, content, initial }: Props) => {
    const [isOpen, { toggle }] = useToggle(startOpen);
    const [height, setHeight] = useState<any>(null);

    const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (ref.current?.offsetHeight) setHeight(ref.current?.offsetHeight);
     }, [ref.current?.offsetHeight, isOpen]);
  return (
    <Container onClick={toggle}>
       <ContainerContent
        ref={ref}
        isOpen={isOpen}
        initial={initial}
        height={height}
        >
    {content}
   </ContainerContent>
   <Expanded>
    <Caret open={isOpen} />
   </Expanded>
  </Container>
 );
};
```

Styled-component:

```
const indentHeight = ({ height }: Props) => `height: ${height}px;`;

export const ContainerContent = styled.div`
  overflow: hidden;
  ${indentHeight}
  ${({ isOpen, initial }: Props) =>
    !isOpen &&
     css`
      display: -webkit-box;
      max-width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      white-space: normal;
      word-wrap: normal;
     -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
     -webkit-line-clamp: ${initial};
   `};

  transition: height 3s ease;
 `;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't make a transition from a `height: 0` to `height: auto`, you have 2 possibilities :

- Provide a `height` to your styled component (so you have to get the content height before applies to your component). And add the css inline (to avoid a new generation of a class if the content is going to change multiple times) like so:

```js
<ContainerContent style={{ height: myHeight}}>
    {content}
</ContainerContent>
```

- Use a hack : Use a `max-height` instead of `height`. But the `max-height` have to be at-least bigger than the maximum value of the content height (or your content will be cut or will overrides the container). I tried this one time but I feel it was a little bit laggy when you define a max-height that is too big. So I prefer the first solution.

Comment: Snippet is not working :( Also not working on my sample

Comment: Yea I know it was to illustrate my point . It's a bit more complex, if you have it on codesandbox or whatever I'll able to help you more

Comment: Thanks! I'm attaching the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-dew-cdtbd?file=/src/Collapse.jsx

Comment: If I understood correctly, is that what you wanted to do?https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-christian-2opxo?file=/src/Collapse.jsx

Comment: Do you have some news @Shira ?

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I decided to go with react-collapsed so I wouldn’t have to worry about the animation. Thanks again